# Where to set environment variables for all users

Tags: bash, environment-variables

Apologies in advance if this question is very simplistic! I have Ubuntu 12.04. I manually installed Maven by downloading the binary tarball file and extracting it to the /opt/ folder. I then set the relevant export variables with the following commands:

```
export M2_HOME=/opt/apache-maven-3.0.5
export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin
```

For good measure, I added these into the /home/andrew/.bashrc file (with andrew being the main user profile). However, I later realised that obviously this only set the path variables for that particular user. When I change to a secondary user, they don't detect the maven installation as they don't have the export variables.

How do I set global variables to govern something like this?

Comment: The above link will answer your question, but, IMO, it is better to place your binary in `/usr/local` , /usr/local/bin, for example, is on your path. Better, I would use this ppa - https://launchpad.net/~natecarlson/+archive/maven3

Comment: So if I install Maven to /usr/local/ does that mean I don't need to export any variables as the location is already on a global path?

Comment: If the tar ball is a single binary, put it in /usr/local/bin and it will be on your path. If there is more then a single binary, you would need to put the pieces in the correct location. In general, IMO, it is best to use a ppa and a .deb, see https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Package_management_system It is written for Fedora, but the concept applies to all distros.

Comment: To throw in yet another opinion, I'd also consider the possibility of installing in the default location and then adding symlinks from /usr/local/bin to $M2_HOME.  This often makes cleaning up easier than if you had installed in /usr/local.